# Non-static method CSaleOrderChange::GetList()

Tags: php, битрикс

После переноса сайта на новый сервер битрикс ругается:

```
Deprecated: Non-static method CSaleOrderChange::GetList() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in local/components/customtheme/base.order_detail/component.php on line 404
```

Код который вызывает первый депрекейтед:

```
$rr = CSaleOrderChange::GetList(array("ID"=>"DESC"),array("ORDER_ID" => $arParams['ID']));
```

После чего сразу вываливает фаталити:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CBitrixComponent::getEntity() in /bitrix/modules/sale/mysql/order_change.php on line 108
```

Модуль интернет магазина стандартный. На новом сервере версия php 5.6. На прошлом была 7 и все работало. Есть смысл менять версию php или это не решит проблему?

На всякий случай - код метода https://bxapi.ru/src/?module_id=sale&name=CSaleOrderChange::GetList

Comment: Модуль стандартный, а вот компонент в котором происходит вызов нет. Версию php поменять стоит

Comment: Помогло обновление версии php до 7.1